# How to disable auto dart formatting code into Android Studio

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio

In context of you would like to write code formatted in another way that the dart standard format teams developers decided (no judgment about that).

The constraint for respect those opinionated formatting it seems to be to strong.

But does exist any tricks or hacks for coding into Dart language with your self coding format ?

General response are allow and also for Android Studio IDE to.

- how to disable dartfmt in Android Studio
- how to disable dartfmt in CLI
- if we can't disabled this format, can we change this ?
- What kind of hacks can we set up  for change formatting ?

**WARNING (not debate here)** : This is not a policy, philosophical or discussion about formatting code question.This is just a technical questions about skip the official formatting code in Dart.

**BEST DISCUSSION (debate here)** : about this subject can be found here ---> [JetBrains users tought](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-328303/?_gl=1*f73zoe*_ga*ODM2OTk5ODMwLjE2ODYyNDgyNDc.*_ga_9J976DJZ68*MTY5NTIwNTQ5My4zNS4wLjE2OTUyMDU0OTMuNjAuMC4w&_ga=2.202748497.1936809756.1695205494-836999830.1686248247#focus=Comments-27-4391578.0-0)

*Thank you for all developers to help another developers for writing Dart code how we like and thank you do not create infinite debate about each personnal insight formatting code.*

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the feature of autoformat on save, add this line to your settings.json (press ctrl+shift+p to open the command palette and type settings and it shows you the settings.json)

```
"editor.formatOnSave": false,
```

The settings.json is a json so it must have the enclosure of a json, a complete settings json could be

```
{
"dart.lineLength": 150,
"[dart]": {
    "editor.rulers": [
        150
    ],
},
"editor.formatOnSave": false,
"editor.guides.bracketPairs": true,
"editor.cursorBlinking": "expand",
"editor.minimap.autohide": true,
```

}

Good luck!

Comment: There is nothing settings.json file in my project